# meshlab, reducing vertices, file-size

Tags: file, size, reduce, vertices

is it possible to reduce the number of vertices from 1.500.000 to a total nuber of 500.000?
An other option is to reduce the filesize under 250MB- now it is 370MB (.OBJ)

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is Quadric decimation, located at:

```
filters >> Remeshing, Simplification and Reconstruction >> Quadric edge collapse decimation
```

There, you can specify the total number of faces in the final mesh, as some other options which may speed up the process.

Quadric decimation will reduce the number of facets (and therefore vertices) to some specified value and in such a way as to minimize the changes to the mesh's geometry.